# Rewriting regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6, regular-language

```
re.compile('(?<!\(\s*)SELECT.*?FROM')
```

I want to compile the regular expression in python 2.6 but I got an error in compiling.

The re module in python will not support */+/?, which the length is not determined, in lookbehind in regex.

Someone has commented to suggest me to use regex, which a third party module. However, I could not use a third party in the company server.

Could anybody help me to rewrite the regex?

```
Target: "( SELECT blablabla" <- This could not be matched. 
"  SELECT blablabla" <- This could be matched, I mean no matter how many whitespace in front of the SELECT the string will always be matched.
```

Comment: You using \s* inside a lookbehind. they need to be of fixed size.

Comment: You cannot have a variable-length lookbehind. The quantifiers `*` and `*?` can be of any length, hence variable, hence not legal in python.

Comment: @Jerry `regex` module supports variable length lookbehind.

Comment: give us the error and an example of expression that you want to compile !

Comment: @AvinashRaj The regex module is not the default module.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's not a default module. So could you please help me rewrite the regex in an alternative way?

Comment: use this `(?<!\()\s*SELECT.*?FROM` regex and trim out the leading spaces.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It depends on your perspective. Regardless, it is still illegal in python without external modules, which is the default, and as long as the regex module remains a non-default module.

Comment: so you mean third party imports are illegal in python.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I will have to write the code in a server which will not allow third party.

Comment: @JackieLam you mean it matches `( SELECT blablabla FROM` also?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes. It matches "( SELECT blablabla FROM", which I don't expect it to do so.

Comment: @AvinashRaj If you want them to be illegal, you're free to think so, I can't do anything about that. @ Jackie: Please update your question with your new question. Now that you know you cannot use this regex, provide some example inputs and expected matches.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Two space ahead of SELECT could be matched. I made a mistake.

Comment: @JackieLam as Jerry said, update your question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thx. I've already update my question.

Comment: @JackieLam Is [this](http://regex101.com/r/qW2mE8/1) what you are looking for? Sorry, I still couldn't understand your question properly; what you wanted exactly from the input. If this is right, then I don't think you can avoid a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x not support variable length lookbehind, cou can use the module `regex` instead of `re` or change your pattern:

```
re.compile('(?<!\()\s*SELECT.*?FROM')
```

Comment: correct this `Python 2.x not support variable length lookbehind`,i donno about the versions below 2.7 but 2.7 does through regex module.